# Mysql Group Join Optimization Issue

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize this query it returns multiple rows from the building_rent_prices and the building_weather and then groups them and calculates the average of their field. So far the tables are all under a million rows yet it takes several seconds, does anyone know how i could optimize this from composite indexes or rewriting the query? I'm assuming it should be able to be a 100ms or quicker query but so far it seems like it cant

```
SELECT b.*
     , AVG(r.rent)
     , AVG(w.high_temp)
  FROM buildings b
  LEFT 
  JOIN building_rent_prices r
    ON r.building_id = b.building_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN building_weather w
    ON w.building_id = b.building_id 
 WHERE w.date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE + INTERVAL 4 DAY
   AND r.date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE + INTERVAL 10 day
 GROUP  
    BY b.building_id
 ORDER  
    BY AVG(r.rent) / b.square_feet DESC
 LIMIT 10;
```

Explain said the following:

1   SIMPLE  building_rent_prices range

1   SIMPLE  buildings eq_ref

1   SIMPLE  building_weather ref

Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

Using where

Using where; Using index

Im working on some test data heres the create table

```
CREATE TABLE building(
building_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name VARCHAR(255),
square_feet INT
);

CREATE TABLE building_weather(
building_weather_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
building_id INT,
weather_date DATE,
high_temp INT
);

CREATE TABLE building_rates(
building_rate_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
building_id INT,
weather_date DATE,
rate double
);

ALTER TABLE building_rates INDEX(building_id);
ALTER TABLE buildings INDEX(building_id);
ALTER TABLE building_weather INDEX(building_id);
```

This seems to working in under 1 second based on DRapp's answer without indexes(I still need to test that its valid)

```
select 
  B.*, 
  BRP.avgRent, 
  BW.avgTemp
   from 
   ( select building_id,
            AVG( rent ) avgRent
         from
            building_rent_prices
         where
            date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + 10
         group by
            building_id
         order by
            building_id ) BRP
     JOIN buildings B
        on BRP.building_id = B.building_id
     left join ( select building_id,
                        AVG( hi_temp ) avgTemp
                     from building_weather 
                     where date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + 10
                     group by building_id) BW
        on BRP.building_id =  BW.building_id
   GROUP BY BRP.building_id
 ORDER BY BRP.avgRent / 1 DESC
   LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Put `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for every table from the query.

Comment: Have you tried the EXPLAIN command?

Comment: You can change the `left join` to `inner join`, because the `where` clause is undoing the outer join.  In addition, your averages are probably wrong because of the cross join effect.

Comment: Thanks, I made the switch to inner join, so far no change in performance though

Comment: I can work on a show create table but the example i gave is a simplified version that i used to recreate the issues i was experiencing it seems to be something to do with grouping by the building_id when joining to two tables on it

Comment: Using filesort means that DB stored some data to disk, check your RAM size. As for indexes - both date columns in where clausule shuld have one, so all colums used in JOIN clausule. The rent and hi_temp colums - try them too. Dont forget to analyse tables, so indexes can be processed. Also try optimalize tables, if they are this big and frequenty used - that can help too.

Comment: I got my buffer pool size by the following: show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size%';
innodb_buffer_pool_size 3221225472

Comment: @CorwinCZ "Using filesort means that DB stored some data to disk" --- no it does not. It means that during sort it used data pages directly.

Comment: hi zerk, is the create table i provided what you need or are there specific things you are looking for?

Comment: You are asking for query performance advice. That's impossible to offer without knowing what indexes you have in your tables. The request for `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output is shorthand for "show us everything about those tables.

Comment: Isn't the create table above sufficient? the issues seems to be mostly with how my query was written?

Comment: The _outer_ `GROUP BY BRP.building_id` is not needed now.

Comment: You need at least 5.6 in order to get the efficiency of indexing the subqueries.  Without it, the query will get a lot slower as the number of buildings increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at this query in detail.  You want to report two different kinds of averages for each building. You need to compute those in separate subqueries. If you don't you'll get the cartesian combinatorial explosion.

One is an average of eleven days' worth of rent prices.  You get that data with this subquery:

```
          SELECT building_id, AVG(rent) rent
            FROM building_rent_prices
           WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY
           GROUP BY building_id
```

This subquery can be optimized by a [compound covering index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html) on `building_rent_prices`, consisting of `(date, building_id, rent)`.

The next is an average of five days' worth of temperature.

```
          SELECT building_id, AVG(high_temp) high_temp
            FROM building_weather
           WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 DAY
           GROUP BY building_id
```

This can be optimized by a compound covering index on `building_weather`, consisting of `(date, building_id, high_temp)`.

Finally, you need to join these two subqueries to your `buildings` table to generate the final result set.

```
SELECT buildings.*, a.rent, b.high_temp
  FROM buildings
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT building_id, AVG(rent) rent
            FROM building_rent_prices
           WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY
           GROUP BY building_id
       ) AS a ON buildings.building_id = a.building_id
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT building_id, AVG(high_temp) high_temp
            FROM building_weather
           WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 DAY
           GROUP BY building_id
       ) AS b ON buildings.building_id = b.building_id
 ORDER BY a.rent / buildings.square_feet DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Once the two subqueries are optimized, this one doesn't need anything except the `building_id` primary key.

In summary, to speed up this query, create the two compound indexes mentioned on the `building_rent_prices` and `building_weather` queries.

Comment: It performed very fast, but in order to get more than one results I had to add group by buildings.building_id ORDER BY a.rent / buildings.square_feet DESC
 LIMIT 10 which took over 3 seconds

Answer (score 1):

First, your query to the WEATHER based table is only for 4 days, the RENT PRICES table is for 10 days.  Since you don't have any join correlation between the two, you will result in a Cartesian result of 40 records per one building ID.  Was that intentional or just not identified as an oops...

Second, I would adjust the query as I have below, but also, I have adjusted BOTH WEATHER and RENT PRICES tables to reflect the same date range period.  I start with an sub query of just the prices and group by building and date, then join to buildings, then another sub query to weather grouped by building and date.  But here, I join from the rent prices sub query to the weather sub query on both building ID AND date so it will at most retain a 1:1 ratio.  I don't know why weather is even a consideration spanning date ranges.

However to help with indexes, I would suggest the following

```
Table                Index on
buildings            (Building_ID)  <-- probably already exists as a PK
building_rent_prices (date, building_id, rent)
building_weather     (date, building_id, hi_temp)
```

The purpose of the index is to take advantage of the WHERE clause (date first), THEN the GROUP BY ( building ID), and is a COVERING INDEX (includes the rent).  Similarly for the building weather table for same reasons.

```
select 
      B.*, 
      BRP.avgRent, 
      BW.avgTemp
   from 
       ( select building_id,
                AVG( rent ) avgRent
             from
                building_rent_prices
             where
                date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY
             group by
                building_id
             order by
                building_id ) BRP

         JOIN buildings B
            on BRP.building_id = B.building_id

         left join ( select building_id,
                            AVG( hi_temp ) avgTemp
                         from
                            building_weather 
                         where
                            date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY
                         group by
                            building_id ) BW
            on BRP.building_id =  BW.building_id

   GROUP BY 
      BRP.building_id

   ORDER BY 
      BRP.avgRent / B.square_feet DESC

   LIMIT 10;
```

CLARIFICATION...

I cant guarantee the execution order, but in essence, the two ( queries ) for BPR and BW aliases, they would be done and executed quickly before any join took place.  If you wanted the average across the (in my example) 10 days vs a per-day join, then I have removed the "date" as a component of the group, so each will return respectively at most, 1 per building.

Now, joining to the building table on just the 1:1:1 ratio will limit the records in the final result set.  This should take care of your concern of the average over those days in question.

Comment: Thank you, I had a theory that the Cartesian might be a issue, can you please help explain the order that your example executes in? I believe it is frst getting the building prices limited to the date_range,  then joining to buildings which has already joined to weather limited on its date ranges?

Comment: If the intent was to get the average over the period of days would I want to only group by building_id rather than both building_id and date?

Comment: @kevinn2065, see answer for clarification

Comment: Your solution performs well but is slightly slower than the one I have posted below and i find it harder to read, Thanks for all of your help it lead me to discovering the solution below!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use CURDATE + 4:

```
mysql> select CURDATE(), CURDATE() + 30, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY;
+------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
| CURDATE()  | CURDATE() + 30 | CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY |
+------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
| 2015-03-15 |       20150345 | 2015-04-14                  |
+------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
```

Add `INDEX(building_id)` to the second and third tables.

If those don't fix it; come back with a revised query and schema, and I will look deeper.

Comment: Thank you, I hope that helps others if they see this(Ill correct it to not use that), I used interval like your example in my code that was my error in transcription to the simpler example

Comment: I have indexed building_id on all tables it seems to be related to the cartesian as suggested by DRapp

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has issues similar to mine the solution is to GROUP each table you would like to join using building_id that way you are joining one to one with every average. Ollie Jones query with JOIN rather than LEFT JOIN is the closest answer if you do not want results that don't have data in all tables. Also The main issue I had was that I forgot to place an index on a avg(low_temp) column so the INDEXES. What I learned from this is that if you do an aggregated function in your select it belongs in your indexes. I added low_temp to it.

building_weather  (date, building_id, hi_temp, low_temp) AS suggested by Ollie and DR APP

```
ALTER TABLE building_weather ADD index(date, building_id, hi_temp, low_temp);

SELECT buildings.*, a.rent, b.high_temp, b.low_temp
  FROM buildings
  JOIN (
      SELECT building_id, AVG(rent) rent
        FROM building_rent_prices
       WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY
       GROUP BY building_id
   ) AS a ON buildings.building_id = a.building_id
  JOIN (
      SELECT building_id, AVG(high_temp) high_temp, AVG(low_temp) low_temp
        FROM building_weather
       WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 DAY
       GROUP BY building_id
   ) AS b ON buildings.building_id = b.building_id
 ORDER BY a.rent / buildings.square_feet DESC
 LIMIT 10
```